# Create a load balancer for existing ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

After creating a service without an LB, is there a way to create an LB for the service after the fact?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

for some reason the UI doesn't seem to allow me to do this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, attaching an Application Load Balancer and TargetGroup must be done at service creation. It can't be added after. You'll have to delete and re-create the service.

Comment: Why is it only possible to choose an Application Load Balancer? I am trying to create a service that doesn't use http.

Comment: It should be supported according to this... not sure if the UI allows it, but it would certainly be supported through the API.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/load-balancer-types.html#nlb