# Create load balancer for ECS service without one

Tags: amazon-ecs

I created an ECS service without a load balancer.
Is there a way to add a load balancer to an existing service, or will I have to create a brand new service in order to add a load balancer?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385899/create-a-load-balancer-for-existing-ecs-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a load balancer for existing ECS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385899/create-a-load-balancer-for-existing-ecs-service)